# How to select all columns in a row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a script for Google Sheets and would like to select all the columns in a given row. I know I can do the converse and select all rows in a given column using something like `sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues()`

Is there an equivalent syntax for selecting all the columns (non-empty, preferably) in Row A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google sheets syntax for an entire row is: "A1:1" (row 1) or "A2:2", (row 2) etc. So that you could use that in your script.

GAS also has:

```
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
```

which could allow you to create the range dynamically within your code.

```
row = "A1:"+lastColumn;
```

I think the difficulty is around 'non-empty', Do you mean stop at the first empty column, or the last, is a key question? Assuming the first, then the following might help:

```
function last_column() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = [];
  values = sheet.getRange("A1:1").getValues(); 
  // getValues() returns a multi-dimensional array, so syntax
  // for the entire row is values[0] 
  for (var i = 0; i < values[0].length; i++) {
    if (values[0][i] === "") {
      Logger.log("found empty column: %s",i+1);
      break;
    }
  }
  return i+1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I meant stop at the first empty column so I'll give your code a try!

Answer (score 3):

The columns equivalent of `"A1:A"` is:

```
"A1:1"
```